# Python Netmiko, Can I point my script to a text gile that has a list of IPs?

Tags: python, netmiko

Here is my script....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y9eS.jpg

Instead of having the list of IPs in the ip_list section, is there a way I can point it to text file that is a list of all the IPs I want to hit?

Comment: Codes are **TEXT**, so please pose them as **TEXT**. This would help people copy-paste your code into their own editors. People cannot run images of code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your script, and please add code in Question not snapshot.

```
import os
import inspect
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
ip_list = open (root+ "/iplist.txt")
 for ip in ip_list:
       "Your Code here"
```

Comment: Worked perfect thank you